# Does Websphere 8.5 provide an API to interface with an Active Directory using security details configured in Websphere security settings?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, websphere, jndi

I am using Websphere Application Server, that has administrative and application security enabled, which uses LDAP to interface an Active Directory for authentication.

The web application that is deployed to the server is required to be able to retrieve information from this AD, as well as modify information in this AD (such as adding a new user to the AD). I could use JNDI to achieve this, however I need the application to use the settings configured in Websphere to do the connection so that I don't have to maintain multiple sets of LDAP information (one in the application and one in Websphere).

I have searched around but couldn't find anything concrete. The closest I saw was I can configure it as a federated user repository instead of standalone LDAP registry, after which I can retrieve some attribute values, but it does not explain if I am able to modify them.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you will use federated repository, then you can use VMM API. It is quite complex comparing to JNDI or ldap related libraries, but should provide you with features you need.

Start by looking at this page - [Developing with virtual member manager](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wim.doc/developing.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-12-2-4-1-3-31-5&lang=en) - and subpages, you will find some code examples there also.

Comment: I see, thanks very much for the help :) 
I will look through the docs and test it out.